# Why did my tablet just suddenly stop wanting to charge?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, 4g

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab Lte and when I plug it in with its original samsung wall charger that charges any other samsung device I have, It's not charging or showing the charging icon. This just happened suddenly and have never had a problem. It doesn't matter if my tablet is on or off and I have cleared all of my apps. Earlier I left it off and on the charger for two hours and it's charging levels rose two percent. What can I do ????

Answer (score 0):

Sometime the charging part jack in which you enter the chager in tab was damaged or become useless because some shocks or may be broken down so when you push the charger pin inside the tab and push it downward then it start charging this pushing work is of jack but if your jack is useless then you have to slightly push down the charger pin when inside tab. The jack is damaged or not you may know from an expert or from repair shop. But try pushing down slightly the pin near tab wheb it is inserted.